# Insert boolean datatype data from datagridview into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How do I insert the boolean type data from datagridview into SQL Server? When I unchecked the check box in the datagridview, and insert the data:

> the error conversion of from type DBNull to type String is not valid.

```vb
Dim index As Integer
Dim selectedRow = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(index)

Try
    For I = 0 To Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        'Dim GRNo As String
        Dim StockCode As String = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("STKID").Value
        Dim StockName As String = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("STKNAME").Value
        Dim GRQuantity As Double = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("GRQTY").Value
        Dim StockCost As Double = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("COST").Value
        Dim BatchControl As Boolean = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("BATCHCTR").Value
        Dim StockBatchID As String = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("BATCHID").Value
        Dim StockExpDate As Date = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("EXPDATE").Value
        Dim StockTaxCode As String = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("TAXCODE").Value
        Dim StockTaxAmount As Double = Quantum_GR.DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells("TAXAMT").Value



        sqlcon.Open()
        If StockCode <> "" Then
            Dim grquery As String = "INSERT INTO GRT(GRNO,STKID,STKNAME,GRQTY,COST,BATCHCTR,BATCHID,EXPDATE,TAXCODE,TAXAMT) VALUES ('" & GRID & "','" & StockCode & "','" & StockName & "'," & GRQuantity & "," & StockCost & ",'" & BatchControl & "','" & StockBatchID & "','" & StockExpDate & "','" & StockTaxCode & "'," & StockTaxAmount & ")"
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(grquery, sqlcon)
            sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqlcmd.Dispose()
        End If
        sqlcon.Close()

        sqlcon.Open()
        SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE GRT SET TCOST=ROUND(GRQTY*COST,2)", sqlcon)
        sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd)
        sqldataset = New DataSet
        sqlda.Fill(sqldataset)
        sqlcon.Close()
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Stop everything you're working on and go read about SQL Injection. Then, fix the code to use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Why not simply bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`?  Then you don;t need any code at all to transfer data because it happens automatically.

Comment: That last tsql statement ("UPDATE ...") just updated EVER SINGLE ROW in GRT. Not just the one you inserted - all of them. Is that really your goal? And why do you need another statement to do that? Why are you not doing this in your insert statement? Consider doing this in the database by making that column (TCOST) a computed column if it is always calculated as specified in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
  Dim index As Integer
        Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)

        Try
            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                'Dim GRNo As String
                Dim StockCode As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("STKID").Value
                Dim StockName As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("STKNAME").Value
                Dim GRQuantity As Double = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("GRQTY").Value
                Dim StockCost As Double = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("COST").Value
                Dim BatchControl As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("BATCHCTR").Value)
                Dim StockBatchID As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("BATCHID").Value
                Dim StockExpDate As Date = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("EXPDATE").Value
                Dim StockTaxCode As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("TAXCODE").Value
                Dim StockTaxAmount As Double = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("TAXAMT").Value



                sqlcon.Open()
                If StockCode <> "" Then
                    Dim grquery As String = "INSERT INTO GRT(GRNO,STKID,STKNAME,GRQTY,COST,BATCHCTR,BATCHID,EXPDATE,TAXCODE,TAXAMT) VALUES ('" & GRID & "',@StockCode,@StockName,@GRQuantity,@StockCost,@BatchControl,@StockBatchID,@StockExpDate,@StockTaxCode," &  & ")"
                    Dim sqlparams(8) As SqlClient.SqlParameter
                    sqlparams(0) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    sqlparams(0).Value = CType(StockCode, String)
                    sqlparams(1) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    sqlparams(1).Value = CType(StockName, String)
                    sqlparams(2) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@GRQuantity", SqlDbType.Float)
                    sqlparams(2).Value = CType(GRQuantity, Double)
                    sqlparams(3) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockCost", SqlDbType.Float)
                    sqlparams(3).Value = CType(StockCost, Double)
                    sqlparams(4) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@BatchControl", SqlDbType.Bit)
                    sqlparams(4).Value = CType(BatchControl, Boolean)
                    sqlparams(5) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockBatchID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    sqlparams(5).Value = CType(StockBatchID, String)

                    sqlparams(6) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockExpDate", SqlDbType.Date)
                    sqlparams(6).Value = CType(StockExpDate, Date)
                    sqlparams(7) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockTaxCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    sqlparams(7).Value = CType(StockTaxCode, String)
                    sqlparams(8) = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StockTaxAmount", SqlDbType.Float)
                    sqlparams(8).Value = CType(StockTaxAmount, Double)
                    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(grquery, sqlcon)

                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sqlcmd.Dispose()
                End If
                'sqlcon.Close()

                'sqlcon.Open()
                SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE GRT SET TCOST=ROUND(GRQTY*COST,2)", sqlcon)
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlcon.Close()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: This cannot work neither. Error: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other type.